# Запуск нескольких команд в одном процессе

Tags: python, subprocess

Как запустить несколько shell-команд в рамках одного процесса?
Синтетический пример: я хочу создать директорию и в ней поддиректорию.

Если я сделаю так:

```
subprocess.call('mkdir dir', shell=True)
subprocess.call('cd dir', shell=True)
subprocess.call('mkdir subdir', shell=True)
```

То каждая команда выполнится в своем подпроцессе, и вместо dir/subdir я получу dir и subdir на одном уровне.

Вариант

```
command = 'mkdir dir && cd dir && mkdir dir2'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Выглядит не очень, и не подойдет, если я хочу получить returncode или stdout каждой комманды.

P.s. os.chdir() тоже не то, вопрос именно в том, **Как запустить несколько shell-команд в рамках одного процесса?**

Comment: А чем не устраивает - cmd1; cmd2 ... ?

Comment: Как вы узнаете где вывод одной команды заканчивается и где начинается вывод другой команды? Если процесс один, то о каком returncode может идти речь. Если mkdir не встроена в shell, то без создания дополнительного процесса (если не использовать `mkdir -p dir/subdir` и запускать без shell) не обойтись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос уже содержит код, который несколько shell-команд запускает внутри одной shell:

```
rc = subprocess.call("a && b && c", shell=True)
```

Для читаемости больших команд, можно тройные кавычки с многострочными командами употреблять `"""..."""`.

Если не хотите `&&` использовать, то в зависимости от вашей задачи можете аналог `set -e -o pipefail` в начало добавить (вместе с `executable='/bin/bash'`).

Чтобы *"получить returncode или stdout каждой комманды."*, вы можете выводить статус каждой команды, вставляя аналог `echo $?` после каждой команды, и использовать [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html), чтобы вывод после появления приглашения (prompt), когда индивидуальная команда завершилась легко вытащить. См.  [Multiple inputs and outputs in python subprocess communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28616018/4279).

Очевидно, что если вы запускаете команды, которые не являются встроенными в shell, то одним процессом не обойдёшься (каждая внешняя команда запускает как минимум один новый OS процесс).

Также, чтобы корректно вывод вытащить, следует выставить значение `$PS1`, так чтобы оно не могло встретиться в выводе ваших команд. К примеру, если вы разделяете вывод по `'> '`, то это может сломаться если любая из команд напечатает `'> '`. Посмотрите [как `pexpect.pxssh.set_unique_prompt()` и `.prompt()`
 методы реализованы](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pexpect/pxssh.html).

Answer (score 0):

Юзайте `subprocess.Popen`. В нем процесс конфигурируется и работает отдельно от потока python-программы.

Comment: Добавьте пример кода. Ибо это не ответ.

Comment: Ответ что всегда должен быть с кодом? Я сказал что надо для паралельной работы комманд, писать код за автора не буду